# JQuery datepicker sometimes don't open

Tags: jquery, datepicker, calendar

I've tried many things. For example

at first I had just this code :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        ,   duration: "fast"
    });
});
```

Then I've tried using document.ready after that I also tried

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
                                   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                                      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                                   });
                                })
```

I also tried writing scripts at the end of the document, but none of these have worked. What should I do? I need this for creating custom calendar 'cause I want to style calendar and default  is limited, I can style it. That's why I wanted to have custom calendar and wanted to use datepicker but it doesn't pop up sometimes. So I'm also opened to the other ideas of maaking custom calendar :D

my code looks like this : js:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"      ,   duration: "fast"
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"> </script>                                    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<div class="wrapper">
    <label for="datepicker">select date
        <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    </label>
 </div>
```

And the rest is styling.

sometimes when I click on it, calendar pops up , but sometimes not

Comment: Does the element exist on the page before you call your jQuery?

Comment: Open your browser console (F12, select console), run your code, look for any error messages - include them in your question (via [edit]).

Comment: Sounds like you are either missing jquery script src or you don't have a datepicker script src.

Comment: *sometimes*?  So it does work other times?   Can you include more code, ideally a working snippet that shows it not working.

Comment: my code looks like this : 
js:   `$( function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
  , duration: "fast"
 });
} );`


html: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.js"> </script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 <label for="datepicker">select date
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
 </label>
</div> `

And the rest is styling